# Google Cloud Run, how to use config maps

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

There is a very light section in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/run/deploy#--set-config-maps) to show that there is a `--set-config-maps` flag which can be set when deploying a cloud run service.

I am looking for an actual example of how these can be used when there is a large number of config vars to be passed in, and from where they can come.

Currently now I am manually passing each one:

```
gcloud run deploy SERVICE --image gcr.io/PROJECT/SERVICE --platform managed
  --set-env-vars APP_CONFIG_MODULE=config.DevConfig 
  --set-env-vars FLASK_ENV=development
  # ...
```

Comment: You are using managed cloud run, but configmaps only work on cloud run for anthos (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/using-configmaps)

Comment: Note that you do not need to pass all environment variables at every deployment: once you have set them, they will be carried over for the next deployment.

Comment: @Steren not sure if that is actually a good way of doing things - could easily lead to lots of env vars hanging around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConfigMaps API only exists on Kubernetes so only Cloud Run for Anthos supports it.

The documentation over at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/using-configmaps makes this very clear. I recommend reading Cloud Run docs instead of gcloud docs to find out.

The `gcloud [...] --help` also has a sentence:

> Only applicable if connecting to Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on Google Cloud or Cloud Run for Anthos deployed on VMware. Specify --platform=gke or --platform=kubernetes to use:

and the `--set-config-maps` option is actually under this category, but it's easy to miss while you’re browsing the `--help` on a web page vs in a terminal reading from top to the bottom.